# UI5 Application breaks when called as Component

Tags: jquery, sapui5

So, I have this UI5 Application which works perfectly fine when called thru index.html, however it breaks (resources not found, failed to load,404 error etc) when I try to call it as Component. Both the applications (Caller & Callee) are on Gateway

Here is the application folder structure.
callee_app-Struct.jpg

```
link to GitHub - https://github.com/mailsandip/component_test
```

all the views are under zui5_trip_confirmation -> views folder..The images and models are in the respective folders.

The component.js is under the folder Component and is defined as

```
// define a new UIComponent  
jQuery.sap.declare("components.Component");  
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.UIComponent");  
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.commons.Button");  
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.table.Table");  
//new Component  
sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("components.Component", {  
    metadata : {  
        properties : {  
            text: "string"  
        }  
    }  
});  
components.Component.prototype.createContent = function(){  
/* trying to register the path zui5_trip_confirmation where all the views are stored */  
sap.ui.localResources("zui5_trip_confirmation");  
// jQuery.sap.registerModulePath('zui5_trip_confirmation','/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zui5_trip_conf/zui5_trip_confirmation');  
    this.oView = sap.ui.jsview("idHome", "zui5_trip_confirmation.views.Home");  
     return this.oView;   
};
```

The caller application calls it as

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath('components','/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zui5_trip_conf/components');
var oComp1 = sap.ui.getCore().createComponent({
        name: "components",
        id: "Comp1",
        settings: {text: "Hello World"}
    });

    var oCompCont1 = new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer("CompCont1", {
        component: oComp1
    });
    oCompCont1.placeAt("content");
```

When I run the caller application, I get resource not found errors on the console. Basically the Component is not able to resolve the path to the views/models/images.

What could be wrong here?

Regards
Sandip

Answer (score 1):

With

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath('components','/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zui5_trip_conf/components')
```

You tell the core to look for everything that starts with "components" in "/sap/bc/[...]".

Then you say that the component name is "components". Shouldn't that be "components.Component"?

**Ok, Update with Example:**

(I hope this makes it clearer)

The most important part: We register the path to the folder of the component file and assign it a prefix. Inside the component we start every single Object/Element/Control/etc. with the same prefix as the component. (In your case: "zui5_conf_try").

I created the example on my server: http://dev.himmelrath.net/ui5/so_componentExample/ and you can download all the files here: http://dev.himmelrath.net/ui5/so_componentExample.zip

Ouside the component, when creating the ComponentContainer in the index.html, we register the path to all the components parts by registering its prefix.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<script src="../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection">
</script>
<script>

// The following line tells the core to look for everything that starts with
// "zui5_conf_try." in the (relative to this html-file's URL) folder "zui5_conf_try"
// This should be equivalent to:
//     jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("zui5_conf_try", "./zui5_conf_try")
sap.ui.localResources("zui5_conf_try")

// Let's skip the component instantiation, ComponentContainer can do that for us
// when we gie it the name of our component.
var oCompCont1 = new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer("CompCont1", {
    name: "zui5_conf_try",
});

oCompCont1.placeAt("content");

</script>

</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**zui5_conf_try/Components.js:**

```
// define a new UIComponent
jQuery.sap.declare("zui5_conf_try.Component");

//jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.Core");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.UIComponent");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.commons.Button");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.table.Table");

//new Component
sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend('zui5_conf_try.Component',{  
    metadata : {
        version : "1.0",
    },  

    // DO NOT overwrite the components init method - it is used internally
    // and calls the createContent-method
    /*
    init: function() {
        alert('init222');       
    },
    */

    createContent: function() {
        // Using sap.ui.localResources('views'); in this context would still 
        // register the path relative to our index.html, not the Component.js
        // so we do not use it. Instead we use the same prefix as the component
        // for our views, because we know that that path must be set correctly
        // if this file has been loaded.

        // This should look for "./views/Home.view.js" relative to the components
        // path, since the components path was registered in the index.html ouside
        // the component
        var view = sap.ui.jsview("idHome", "zui5_conf_try.views.Home");
        return view;
    }
});
```

**zui5_conf_try/views/Home.view.js:**

```
sap.ui.jsview("zui5_conf_try.views.Home", {  

   getControllerName: function() {
      return "zui5_conf_try.views.Home";     
   },

   createContent: function(oController) {
      var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({text:"I am zui5_conf_try.views.Home"});
      oButton.attachPress(oController.handleButtonClicked);
      return oButton;
   }

});
```

**zui5_conf_try/views/Home.controller.js:**

```
sap.ui.controller("zui5_conf_try.views.Home", {
   handleButtonClicked : function() {
        alert("You just clicked the view button...");
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sirion, as per SAP's documentation - its not really required to provide the Component.js, only components would do. This works if I just add an alert inside init() method of Component

Comment: If you create a component with "createComponent", you should use the Component.js - this is a convention. When you use registerModulePath, you just tell the core where to look if you register "xyz" it looks for everything that starts with "xyz." in that path. So "xyz.Component" would look for "xyz/Component.js" while "xyz.controls.MyControl" would try to load "xyz/controls/MyControl.js". It boils down to a very simple string replacement "." -> "/".

Comment: Sirion - if I understood correctly, you saying I would need to mention Component.js explicitly while creating the Component??? The component.js is available under components folder, its just that I didnt mention it while creating. Check this sap docs  https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/guide/NewComponent.html..It is not required to mention it explicitly..

Comment: It is not required explicitly. In the Documentation you can see that the component name ends with ".Component" this is the key.
Example: I say registerModulePath("a.b.c", "xxx") - this means that if I try to load/create "a.b.c.Component" the core qould try to load "xxx/Component.js" - if i try to load "a.b.c.whatever" it would look for "xxx/whatever.js".

Btw: If I remember correctly, localResources("abc") just does a registerModulePath("abc", "abc")

Comment: The Component name does end with .Component. I have declared it as jQuery.sap.declare("zui5_conf_try.Component");  The issue is that the Component is not able to refer to the resources (views/images etc) ..Even though I have defined localResources('views')/localResources('images') within the component - but still its not able to render the views..

Comment: Please update your code then - your above code cannot work like that. How about you show your whole code and a folder tree? The componentName "components" should not work. Change it. After the component is loaded "zui5_trip_confirmation.views.Home" should be loaded from the folder "zui5_trip_confirmation/views" relative to your index.html not from the folder "views" relative to the component - everything inside the component should share the component prefix. Please share your folder structure.

Comment: Sirion - I have uploaded the source codes in github..here is the link https://github.com/mailsandip/component_test...I changed the location of the Component.js file. Right now its directly under WebContent folder of Called App..

Comment: Thanks for the solution, when I add those as below in Component.js , my app could work again.

// define a new UIComponent
jQuery.sap.declare("zui5_conf_try.Component");
//jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.Core");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.UIComponent");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.commons.Button");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.table.Table");

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so looked at it a bit more - looks like the resources are not being loaded by the Component.js , even though there is an explicit loading mentioned

```
--inside component.js ----

sap.ui.localResources('views');
sap.ui.resources('images');

  var view = sap.ui.jsview("idHome", "views.Home");
  return view;

---- exit ----
```

This is what confuses me, the core should have loaded the views with respect to the Component.js location. The same problem happens with images folder.

```
This seems like an issue with the Component framework.
```

Regards
Sandip